# CodeDom Compiler for C#

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, codedom

I have been trying to get CodeDom to work so I can dynamically create code for my application during runtime. However, after many tutorials and trial and error, I have come into a problem I can't seem to pass. I keep getting compiler errors on code that looks exactly like it should. I get "Unrecognized escape sequence '\'" when there is no '\' anywhere in my code.

The errors I get are all on line 1. Here they are in order:
CS1009
CS1056 (3 times in a row)
CS0116

Here is what I have:

The code being compiled:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace sdjkfhj 
{    
    public class Sample 
    {
        public static void main()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Working");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

And the compiler code is as follows:

```
public void Compile(string file)
    {
        var prov = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        prov.Add("CompilerVersion", "v2.0");
        CSharpCodeProvider c = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        ICodeCompiler comp = c.CreateCompiler();

        CompilerParameters param = new CompilerParameters();
        param.GenerateExecutable = true;
        param.OutputAssembly = file + ".exe";
        param.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        param.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll");
        if (c.Supports(GeneratorSupport.EntryPointMethod))
            param.MainClass = "Sample";

        CompilerResults results = comp.CompileAssemblyFromSource(param, file);

        if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (CompilerError CompErr in results.Errors)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Line number " + CompErr.Line + ", Error Number: " + CompErr.ErrorNumber + ", '" + CompErr.ErrorText + ";" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there something I'm not doing to compile it right? Are there things I'm missing? I'm kind of lost here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: which line gives the error? Does it compile in VS?

Comment: Shouldnt `CompileAssemblyFromSource()` contain the `source` instead of the `file`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three things come to mind right away:

1. There are no semicolons in the code you're attempting to compile.
2. If Main is supposed to be your entry point, make it static.
3. Make your source file different than your target file (something like `param.OutputAssembly = file + ".exe";`

Fixing these is really only the first step, you'll also have to configure the assemblies that your output will need to reference, and it wouldn't be a bad idea to set MainClass on the CompilerParameters you're using either.

[A nice example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.mainclass.aspx)

Comment: Edit: I edited the code to represent the changed. -- The semi-colon thing was already put in. I guess I forgot to re-add them before pasting it here. Anyway: Changing Main to static, check. Adding all resource dlls, check. MainClass = "Sample", check. File output name different, check. Result: Same 5 errors on exact same line. This is what I don't get, all these changes make sense but the output doesn't represent that. I've even basically copied the source from msdn with no success. Thanks for your help, but I'll have to keep looking into it.

Comment: Change `CompileAssemblyFromSource` to `CompileAssemblyFromFile`

Comment: Thank you, that was a very simple mistake on my part. After changing it to FromFile and changing MainClass to Namespace.Classname instead of just Classname, I got it to compile. Thank you for pointing it out, all works now.